# Qt select existing file

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I am new to Qt and I want to be able to select a already existing file called `default.ini` which is in the same directory as the exe. I already have some code that allows me to do that, but the user has to manually select the file everytime.

```
 QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "/debug", tr("default (*.ini)"));

  if (file != NULL) {
    try {
      controller_->ConfigurationFileSave(file.toStdString());
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
      Logger::Log(std::string("Failed to save configuration: ") + e.what(), 
      Logger::kError);
    }
  }
```

The program does everything I want it to do in terms of writing/ reading to the file, I just don't want the program to require any user input in opening the file. I understand that the reason I have user input is because I am using the QFileDialog class and I just want to know if there is another class that does it automatically. Thanks

**Edit 1** As per Arun's suggestion I tried to use Qfile. The program now reads from the default.ini config file successfully but it won't save to the config file. Is there an easy way to write to the file?

```
 QFile file("default.ini");
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
 return;

 QString content = file.readAll();

 file.close();

 if (content != NULL) {
   try {
  controller_->ConfigurationFileSave(content.toStdString());
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
  Logger::Log(std::string("Failed to save configuration: ") + e.what(), 
      Logger::kError);
    }
  }
```

**Edit 2** As per Arun's second suggestion:

```
QFile file("default.ini");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text); 
QString line = file.readAll();
file.close();

file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
try {
  controller_->ConfigurationFileSave(line.toStdString());
} catch (std::exception &e) {
  Logger::Log(std::string("Failed to save configuration: ") + e.what(), 
      Logger::kError);
}
file.close();
```

Comment: If you know the directory name, then you can just assign the complete path of your file.

Comment: won't that still cause the "open file" dialog box to appear though?

Comment: when you say "won't save to the config file", what exactly is happening? you must have had some contents in `content`

Comment: When I used the QFileDialog Class, I selected the default.ini file in the "open file" dialog box and I could read and write to the file. Now when I use the QFile method, the GUI recognizes variables that I edited manually in the ini file but I can't write to the file like I could before.

Comment: All this code is in a button handler for a button called 'apply'. So when I edit some variables and click apply, the varaibles used to save to the ini file when i used the QFileDialog method but now they don't save

Comment: Cross-platform warning: If you ever use this code in OS X, it will look for the ini inside the .app package/folder tree and therefore won't be what you expect. The path of the "exe" is /path/to/Program.app/Contents/MacOS/program_executable.

Comment: @Arun yeah that didn't work. I just find it strange that it works fine in the QFileDialog class but it doesn't work in QFile.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @Harvey

Comment: May be  file.close(); creating the problem? the file handle must be kept open.

Comment: If it is a small config file, this may not be the most ideal suggestion but an easy one. Step1: open file in READONLY mode, readAll and close the file handler. Step2: Open file in WRITEONLY mode, save contents and close the file handler.

Comment: I tried what you said but now it has wiped everything off the ini file. I posed an edit of what I did, maybe I missed something

Comment: It is difficult to say what exactly is happening without looking into the implementation of `ConfigurationFileSave`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87433/discussion-between-arun-and-oodan123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file chooser code was passing a filename to `ConfigurationFileSave()`. Here's code to get that file name without interaction:

```
QDir appDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QFileInfo file(appDir, "default.ini");

// file.filePath() or file.absoluteFilePath() here:
controller_->ConfigurationFileSave( ___HERE___ );
```

You can test this in QtCreator by creating a new console application and using this as your main.c:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDir appDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
    QFileInfo file(appDir, "default.ini");

    qDebug() << "        " << file.filePath();
    qDebug() << "        " << file.absoluteFilePath();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
silver:qt_app_dir hchapman$ ls
Makefile            main.cpp            main.o              qt_app_dir          qt_app_dir.pro      qt_app_dir.pro.user
silver:qt_app_dir hchapman$ ./qt_app_dir
     "/Users/hchapman/Desktop/qt_app_dir/default.ini"
     "/Users/hchapman/Desktop/qt_app_dir/default.ini"
silver:qt_app_dir hchapman$ cd ..
silver:Desktop hchapman$ ./qt_app_dir/qt_app_dir
     "/Users/hchapman/Desktop/qt_app_dir/default.ini"
     "/Users/hchapman/Desktop/qt_app_dir/default.ini"
silver:Desktop hchapman$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, sorry i'm new at this but what does the `__HERE__` bit mean?

Comment: Nothing. :) I was just showing you where you should use `file.filePath()`.

Comment: Also, since file is a QFileInfo object, you can test if your file exists (if that matters).

Comment: Thank you for your help you are correct! The guy that posted his answer then deleted it had a simpler answer but I understood yours more. All i had to do was `controller_->ConfigurationFileSave("default.ini");`

Comment: You should use the appdir code. If your app is ever run from another directory, then it will still find the ini location correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical example of how you can do file I/O without using QFileDialog.
This example here uses [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#details)

```
QFile file("default.ini");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();
    process_line(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use your code but the ConfigurationFileSave method requires a string. I added an edit to my question